# Method does not reach Completion Block

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift, storekit

I'm using the `SKStoreProductViewController` to display an iTunes product with the following method. The method gets called, but I get no success or error. Any idea why?:

```
@IBAction func BuySomething(sender : AnyObject) {

    NSLog("%@","called");//gets called

    let storeViewController:SKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController();

    storeViewController.delegate = self;

    var someitunesid:String = "676059878";

    var productparameters = [SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:someitunesid];

    storeViewController.loadProductWithParameters(productparameters, { (success: Bool!,          error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if success {
            NSLog("%@",success)//no call
            self.presentViewController(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
        } else {
            NSLog("%@", error)//no call
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: make sure that your device has AppleID configured for AppStore...

Comment: make sure the product you are targeting is available on the current platform (if app is only iPad it would not load on iPhone, but no error is shown).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For some reasons `SKStoreProductViewController` doesn't work on simulator, you must try it on actual device instead.

I just tried that on actual device and got an screenshot of how it looks like on the actual device after callback was called with success:

And here is the code I've used to do it:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func BuySomething(sender : AnyObject) {

        NSLog("%@","called");//gets called

        let storeViewController:SKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController();

        storeViewController.delegate = self;

        var someitunesid:String = "676059878";

        var productparameters = [SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:someitunesid];

        storeViewController.loadProductWithParameters(productparameters, {
            (success: Bool!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if success {
                NSLog("%@",success)
                self.presentViewController(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
            } else {
                NSLog("%@", error)
            }
            })
    }

    // this is SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate implementation
    func productViewControllerDidFinish(viewController: SKStoreProductViewController!) {

    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm working on ios 8 on both an iphone and an ipad. It's awesome that you got it working though! Funny thing. I've imported StoreKit, linked the library and done everything I think I should. Internet connection is strong...good wifi, good cellular...hmmm...

Comment: just for kicks, could you post the whole swift code? My delegate could be off...but it never reaches the delegate.

Comment: @krisacorn, and the reason you cannot run this one on simulator is that there is not itunes store on somulator

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had. Nothing more, nothing less. I know about the simulator, the docs are pretty clear about it not working with StoreKit. I am working on a device, but still no love. Correct answer regardless of my issues and thanks.

Comment: I'm working with an actual device and still have the same issue. What is weird is that sometimes the completion block gets called, and sometimes not...

Comment: Funny thing that it seems to work (for you) with a string as parameter. The Docs clearly state that the value of `SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier` has to be an instance of `NSNumber`. Doesn't work for me, no matter whether I use a string or a number. Could be due to the fact that the app I'm trying to load wasn't released previously. But I expected a call to the error case at least :(

Comment: I was having the same issue of not working in the simulator. Now testing on a device and works fine. Only once. If you click the button, the store view controller loads, click cancel it dismisses. But try to click on it again and it does nothing. Only works once. I have to force close app, then reopen and again only works once. Any ideas?

Comment: If StoreKit, doesn't find the iTunes ID, it does never return with an error like for example "Item not found" or the like... :-(
That is certainly a bug in StoreKit, because at some point the block should be called with or without result...
Starting a timer which kicks in with a "Not found" alert after an arbitrary amount of seconds is absolutely lame, but I do not see another solution, for people who have for example the "wrong" country set in iTunes Store. In my case I am targeting an App, which only exists in one countries App Store, and so it "hangs", if another store is selected...

Answer (score 0):

Might be I am too late but it only happens when your open app does not support your country/region.

Rather it always works.

Happy Coding!!!!!