# SKStoreProductViewController not showing anything

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I'm trying to present the App Store sheet from inside my app:

https://gist.github.com/valeIT/bf9b357d8ef470fc559c

My ViewController conforms to SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate. It seems like the problem is in "loadProductWithParameters" since I've tried calling presentViewController from outside the completion block and it presents and dismisses just fine, just it's completely empty (a white screen). I've tried passing as dictionary both a string or an nsnumber but nothing changes. Any idea?

Comment: Have you waited some time to see if eventually it loads? If it loads, that is expected behavior, if you don't present the viewcontroller from inside the completion block, it probably won't have time to load its content

Comment: mmm I've waited more than a minute.. And yeah I figured the latter...      
Edit: Nope, doesn't load, waited 5 mins+...

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: mmm all the code related to the question is in the gist... the only thing that's out is written just below it... and self.timer is just a var timer = NSTimer() and my viewController is a simple UIViewController.

Comment: mmm guess it doesn't work on the simulator... Thanks everyone anyways ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709586/method-does-not-reach-completion-block It was even it the docs that it doesn't work... Blind me...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is question crazy old, but I'm having the same problem.

The only part of your gist that looks off is that, according to the docs, the value to `SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier` should be of type `NSNumber` but you have supplied a `String`. Try changing it to

```
vc.loadProductWithParameters([SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : NSNumber(value: 364709193)]
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Hmmm. Odd. When I pass a String in Swift, it works. When I pass an NSNumber if doesn't work. Apple's docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductparameteritunesitemidentifier?language=objc) say NSNumber too...

Answer (score 1):

The `SKStoreProductViewController` class does not support subclassing or embedding, and must be used as-is.

**Important**

If you compile with the iOS 13 SDK, attempting to instantiate a subclass of `SKStoreProductViewController` results in a `runtimeException`.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller)

Comment: This is exactly the reason why my loading always failed with a `Invalid configuration for loading product` and error 0, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that SKStoreProductViewController loadProductWithParameters: fails silently if there are no products to load...  if the product is a Mac application or iPad-only and you're asking for it from an iPhone, or you ask for an iPhone-only app from an iPad, loadProductWithParameters just never returns.

The ol' tried-and-true UIApplication openURL: technique using the iTunes URL gets a response in every case reliably - even for Mac applications - via browser:

```
NSString *itunesiOSURL = @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myiOSapp/id123456789?mt=8";
NSString *itunesMacURL = @"https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/myMacApp/id123456789?mt=8";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:itunesURL]];
```